# My python code stops working after a few iteration

Tags: python, speech-to-text

I'm currently learning how to code with python, and I thought the best way would be learning by doing so I tried to create a voice assistant but it just stops working after a few iterations.

The code below isn't very efficient nor clean, but it works except for the part that it stops after a few iterations of listening.

there are no error mesages nor does the code actually stop it just doesn't do anything

thank you for every suggestion in advance

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import datetime as dt
# import wikipedia
# import webbrowser
import os
# import time
# import subprocess
# import ecapture as ec
# import wolframalpha
# import json
# import requests
# from gtts import gTTS
import random as ran
from docx import Document

document = Document()
note_new = ""
note_complete = ""
adding_more = True

second = dt.datetime.now().second
minute = dt.datetime.now().minute
hour = dt.datetime.now().hour

hour_str = str(hour)
minute_str = str(minute)
second_str = str(second)

time = hour_str + ":" + minute_str + ":" + second_str + " "

# initialising the text to speech engine
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[2].id)

# <editor-fold desc="Listening to the Users input">
# listening to the Users input
statement = ""


def listen():
    global statement

    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        audio = r.listen(source)

        try:
            statement = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')

        except Exception as e:
            # speak("Pardon me, please say that again")
            return "None"
        return statement


# </editor-fold>

# <editor-fold desc="Talking">


def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


# </editor-fold>

# <editor-fold desc="Key Words">
# KeyWord Functions


def hello():
    random_text = ran.randint(1, 3)

    if random_text == 1:
        print("Hello Sir, welcome home.")
        talk("Hello Sir, welcome home.")
    elif random_text == 2:
        print("Hello, welcome home.")
        talk("Hello, welcome home.")
    elif random_text == 3:
        print("Welcome back.")
        talk("Welcome back.")


def minecraft():
    random_text = ran.randint(1, 3)

    if random_text == 1:
        print("Initialising Minecraft...")
        talk("Initialising Minecraft")
    elif random_text == 2:
        print("Minecraft coming right up...")
        talk("Minecraft coming right up")
    elif random_text == 3:
        print("Starting Minecraft")
        talk("Starting Minecraft")

    os.startfile("C:\Spiele\Minecraft\MinecraftLauncher.exe")


def chrome():
    random_text = ran.randint(1, 3)

    if random_text == 1:
        print("Initialising Chrome...")
        talk("Initialising Chrome")
    elif random_text == 2:
        print("Chrome coming right up...")
        talk("Chrome coming right up")
    elif random_text == 3:
        print("Starting Chrome...")
        talk("Starting Chrome")

    os.startfile("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")


def valorant():
    random_text = ran.randint(1, 3)

    if random_text == 1:
        print("Initialising Valorant...")
        talk("Initialising Valorant")
    elif random_text == 2:
        print("Valorant coming right up...")
        talk("Valorant coming right up")
    elif random_text == 3:
        print("Starting Valorant...")
        talk("Starting Valorant")

    os.startfile("C:/Spiele/Riot Games/VALORANT/live/VALORANT.exe")


def aim_lab():

    random_text = ran.randint(1, 3)

    if random_text == 1:
        print("Initialising Aim Lab...")
        talk("Initialising Aim Lab")
    elif random_text == 2:
        print("Aim Lab coming right up...")
        talk("Aim Lab coming right up")
    elif random_text == 3:
        print("Starting Aim Lab...")
        talk("Starting Aim Lab")

    os.startfile("steam://rungameid/714010")


def clock():
    global second
    global minute
    global hour
    global hour_str
    global minute_str
    global second_str

    global time

    second = dt.datetime.now().second
    minute = dt.datetime.now().minute
    hour = dt.datetime.now().hour

    hour_str = str(hour)
    minute_str = str(minute)
    second_str = str(second)

    time = hour_str + ":" + minute_str + ":" + second_str + " "

    print("It's " + hour_str + " hours and " + minute_str + " minutes")
    talk("It's " + hour_str + " hours and " + minute_str + " minutes")


def note():
    global adding_more
    global note_new
    global note_complete
    print("How should i call the note?")
    talk("How should i call the note?")
    listen()
    note_name = statement
    while adding_more:
        print("Ok you can start talking:")
        talk("Ok you can start talking:")
        listen()
        note_new = statement
        print("new: " + note_new)
        note_complete = note_complete + " " + note_new
        print("new: " + note_complete)
        print("Do you want to add more?")
        talk("Do you want to add more?")
        listen()
        if "yes" in statement.lower():
            adding_more = True
        if "no" in statement.lower():
            adding_more = False

    print("printing...")
    talk("printing..")
    note_name_txt = note_name + ".txt"
    note_name_complete = note_name_txt

    f = open(note_name_complete, "w+")
    f.write(note_complete)
    f.close()

    print("ready")
    talk("ready")

    print("should i open the note?")
    talk("should i open the note?")

    listen()
    if "yes" in statement.lower():
        note_name_complete = str(note_name_complete)
        note_name_path = note_name_complete.replace(" ", "_")
        os.startfile("D:/Python/Projekts/Jarvis/" + note_name_complete)


def dice():
    number = 6

    print("What sould be the range")
    talk("What sould be the range")

    listen()

    try:
        number = int(statement)
    except:
        print("I could not understand you sorry Sir!")
        dice()

    random_number = ran.randint(1, number)

    print("The D " + str(number) + " says " + str(random_number))
    talk("The D" + str(number) + "says" + str(random_number))


def stop():
    global hour

    if hour <= 12:
        print("have a good day!")
        talk("have a good day!")

    if 19 >= hour < 12:
        print("Goodbye")
        talk("bye")

    if hour > 19:
        print("Goodnight!")
        talk("Goodnight")

    quit()


# </editor-fold>


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:

        statement = " "

        listen()
        print(statement)

        command = statement.lower()
        if "jarvis" in command:
            if "hello" in command:
                hello()

            if "minecraft" in command:
                minecraft()

            if "chrome" in command:
                chrome()

            if "valorant" in command:
                valorant()

            if "time" in command or "clock" in command:
                clock()

            if "note" in command:
                note()

            if "dice" in command:
                dice()

            if "aim" in command or "lab" in command:
                aim_lab()

            if "stop" in command or "bye" in command or "goodbye" in command or "goodnight" in command:
                stop()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question is not ready to answer, because it is missing debugging details (what is the print-out) and should actually be a [example] to be easy to reproduce. Please read [ask] and refine your question ️

Answer (score 0):

If you report:

> stops working after a few iterations

Then I would look for the *loop* (where iterations happen usually). I found the only obvious loop in the main block:

### Shorten the loops

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        statement = ''  # initialize as empty string
        listen()
        print(statement)
        execute_command(statement.lower())
```

Extracted your command switch into a method `execute_command`:

```py
def execute_command(command):
    if "jarvis" in command:
        if "hello" in command:
            hello()
        if "minecraft" in command:
            minecraft()
        if "chrome" in command:
            chrome()
        if "valorant" in command:
            valorant()
        if "time" in command or "clock" in command:
            clock()
        if "note" in command:
            note()
        if "dice" in command:
            dice()
        if "aim" in command or "lab" in command:
            aim_lab()
        if "stop" in command or "bye" in command or "goodbye" in command or "goodnight" in command:
            stop()
```

Then watch out to the understood `command` that is printed.

Which `command` was the last printed before the loop stopped?

### Design pure functions (returning a value)

This goes hand in hand with another common programming advice:

- Don't use *global variables*!

```py
def listen():
    statement = '' # remove global, make it local and return

    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        audio = r.listen(source)

        try:
            statement = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')

        except Exception as e:
            # speak("Pardon me, please say that again")
            return "None"
        return statement  # you had the return already; use it!
```

Then your *main* (and other usage locations) would change to:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        statement = listen()  # use the return
        print(statement)
        execute_command(statement.lower())
```